# foreach loop doesn't populate select options

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I've been struggling with this for at least an hour to no avail. I'm sure the answer is simple, but I can't figure it out. The foreach loop is what I'm trying to accomplish, but it doesn't work. The for loop works and renders fine. Please help! - Jon

```
<div class="td"><select name="vehYear">
    <?php
    foreach ($veh_year_array as $item)
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item;?>"><?php echo $item;?></option>
    <?php}
    ?>

    <?php
    for ($i = date('Y'); $i > 1950; $i--) {
        echo "<option>$i</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select></div>
```

Comment: are you sure the `$veh_year_array` is populated? maybe try pasting the output of `var_dump($veh_year_array)`?

Comment: @starnzd - If you're doing an edit, it's OK to reformat the OP's code (add/remove line feeds and indentions to make it more readable), but it's not OK to _change_ the original code (changing the actual syntax).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson cheers, good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems your error is the curly bracket `}`. In my environment I received an

> invalid argument error

when pasting your original code. You want to be very careful in PHP since it is a sensitive language.

So exchange this

```
<?php}?>
```

to this

```
<?php }?>
```

Your code should then [execute](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c40627aa5ab10b3c40bda7158a2e5ccb7ba58377)

```
<?php
$veh_year_array =array("Tomato", "Apple", "Orange");

  foreach ($veh_year_array as $item)
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item;?>"><?php echo $item;?></option>
    <?php }?>

    <?php
    for ($i = date('Y'); $i > 1950; $i--) {
        echo "<option>$i</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Baloon Fight. You're exactly right. I wouldn't have imagined such a small thing would make a huge difference. :-/ Cheers. Jonathan

Comment: Also, what environment are you using? I'm using intellij and there were no "invalid argument" errors thrown.

Comment: @StackBoy : I'm using Netbeans latest version. Make sure you test with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` this will catch every PHP errors. Also if you use Mysqli use this `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` Place those pieces of code first thing on every PHP page. Cheers

Comment: Okay I'll try to incorporate the functions you included to catch PHP errors.